# Info about Action MAIN and Category Launcher in Android Manifest

Tags: android, action, categories, launcher

In the Android manifest file, what do you mean by the category Launcher and action MAIN
      
**category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
      
action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"**

 Is it possible to make one activity the laucher and another one the main action?

Comment: Go here you have everything explained http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: @waheed: mark answers to your previous questions as accepted, if you feel those answers actually solved your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activities will very often need to support the `CATEGORY_DEFAULT` so that they can be found by `Context.startActivity()`. So, `CATEGORY_DEFAULT` can appear number of times.

Android does not grab whichever one appears first in the manifest but it starts with activity having `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`.

`CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` : The activity can be the initial activity of a task and is listed in the top-level application launcher.

For more details refer: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Comment: what about action MAIN?

Comment: What do you mean by top level application launcher?

Answer (score 6):

Extending the answer of Balaji, I'll add-up a few things:

For the starters, there could be multiple points of entry to an app. Let's suppose our app has two activities for simplicity.

You can keep the `<intent-filter>` tag in both activities and contain `MAIN` as well as `LAUNCHER` into it. This would create two launchers of the app - and two identical app icons could be physically seen at your app-launcher. You click on one icon - and it'll start one of the activities. You click the other, and it'll start the other activity.

However, if you drop either of `MAIN` or `LAUNCHER` tag from the the second activity, there'll be only one physical launcher for the app which launches the first activity.

Having said that, 
`MAIN` in an activity is used to tell that when the app starts, it'll start with this very activity.