# Android Emulator can't find Launcher Icon

Tags: android

I create an Android project.I run this project on my emulator. 
And a get e message: \GraphicsAndStyles\bin\GraphicsAndStyles.apk installed on device

When I open my emulator I can't see my Launcher icon and I can't start my application.
Can anyone help me about this?

Here is the xml code in my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.graphicsandstyles"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.graphicsandstyles.List"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LIST" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.graphicsandstyles.Styles"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.graphicsandstyles.Themes"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.THEMES" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep both of these inside the intent-filter of the same activity to make icon visible as below:

```
<intent-filter >  
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />   
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>  
</intent-filter>
```

Currently, you kept these two fields seperately  in two separate activities, so please change it to:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.graphicsandstyles.List"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >  
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LIST" />  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />   
            </intent-filter>  
</activity>
```

You can find detailed information about the usage of these two manifest tags [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730982/info-about-action-main-and-category-launcher-in-android-manifest)

Comment: you have had a great many edits where you have only added spurious tags.  Try to look over the entire post as there is much more value that you can add. ... and nice answer +1